# linq imultipleresults - iterate over results

Tags: linq-to-sql

Quick question,

I have a call to a sproc which can return any number of the same resultset.

I have a loop which knows how many are going to be returned at one time, this works great.

Inside the loop it uses getresult() and transforms the data into the specified type say .  This seems to work but when it comes to displaying the data on the page comeing through the BAL to UI i get a weird javascript error of error code 500.

After debugging ive found it is something to do with when the results are transformed into type  .

The  type is one that i have added myself and inside it there are columns that do not map to any entity in the schema.  Will this cause a problem?

I'm getting very frustrated with linq overall, it's very time consuming where i think it should work....it doesnt!

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting a JavaScript error code of 500 which is internal server error this says AJAX to me.  So can you show the code which you are using to fetch the data.  Are you using WCF, Static page Methods.  Are you logging ecxceptions on the server side method used to get the data?

Comment: Please add the comments inside here.  Are you using custom ajax implementations or are you using an update panel?